# ASP.Net client caching on authenticated pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, client

Our web app currently under development has authentication on all the pages.

We can deny a user access to any particular page but have found that if a user had previously opened the page that they can still access the page via the url. [Even if they log out and log in]

Assuming that the page is coming from client cache [Ctrl F5 in IE kicks in the proper authentication behavior or clearing the client cache]

A lot depends on how we have implemented the authentication but a quick fix on our side would be from within the admin section where we deny access to certain pages that we expire client cache for that page.

Is there a way to do this programmatically.

This would mean that client caching would continue to work as normal for all other users that still had access to the page in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this line to your Page base class or any where in a specific page you want to disable caching on.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

Comment: Thanks, so the only reasonable approach would seem to be to disable client caching completely on any page that could have restricted access by role/user. The above command though would seem to disable proxy caching also

Comment: @Liam - I believe so, but it's been a while since I read the documentation on it. Though, in any kind of authentication scheme where page caching is an issue, disabling proxy caching is not such a bad idea.